# C# httpwebrequest - create json body with system library

Tags: c#, json

Is it possible to create a json body for a HttpWebRequest with system libraries? I tried something like the following, but it does not work - i think there is something missing:

```
string json = "{\"Datum\":\"" + sDateTime + "\"," +
                                    "\"ATZ\":\"1\"," +
                                    "\"PZN\":\"2\"," +
                                    "\"Product\":\"3\"," +
                                    "\"Dose\":\"4\"," +
                                    "\"Unit\":\"5\"," +
                                    "\"End\":\"6\"}";
```

Comment: take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-6.0#System_Net_Http_Json_HttpClientJsonExtensions_PostAsJsonAsync__1_System_Net_Http_HttpClient_System_String___0_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_ this should give you a much better way of handling it

Comment: Please don't attempt to generate JSON manually like this. You should either use a dedicated model class or anonymous type and use JSON serialisation - either Json.net or System.Text on .Net Core 3+

Comment: Does the service you're attempting to use have a swagger document? (openapi specification document). Tools like AutoRest and NSwag will consume it and churn out a LOT of C# code that is optimized for calling the API functions. It would take a human days to write equivalent quality/utility code

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Text.Json

Example:

```cs
  public class Data {
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string Atz { get; set; }
  }

  var data = new Data() {
    Datum = DateTime.Now,
    Atz = "1"
  };

  var jsonObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

jsonObject will be contains '**{"Datum":"2021-11-29T14:56:00.5436035+02:00","Atz":"1"}**'

Read more - [JSON serialization and deserialization (marshalling and unmarshalling) in .NET - overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview?pivots=dotnet-6-0)